# display details in collapsible div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an object:

```
public class Person {
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName{get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
   public List<Car> Cars {get; set;}
}
public class Car{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public DateTime Manufactured {get; set;}
}
```

Inside razor view I'm iterating over list of person objects and display its properties

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
   <tr id="@item.Id">
       <td>@item.FirstName </td>
       <td>@item.LastName</td>
       <td>@item.Age </td>
    </tr>
}
```

How can I display list of cars in collapsible `div` when user clicks on a `tr`?

Comment: Try looking at a library like JQueryUI that has lots of different controls that might help you achieve what you want.  Maybe an accordion or something?

Comment: Can you change the structure of the HTML at all? Using a table for collapsible content is not ideal.

Comment: Can you not access it with `@item.Cars.Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made this in Notepad. Maybe you can use this as an inspiration:

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
    <tr id="person-@item.Id" class="person">
       <td>@item.FirstName </td>
       <td>@item.LastName</td>
       <td>@item.Age </td>
    </tr>
    @if (item.Cars != null && item.Cars.Count > 0) {
    <tr class="cars" id="cars-for-person-@item.Id" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
        @foreach (var car in item.Cars){
            <div class="each-car">
                <span class="name">@car.Name</span>
                <span class="name">@car.Manufactured </span>
            </div>
        }
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}

<script>
    $(function() {
        var table = $("table");
        table.on("click", "tr.person", function() {
            $(this).next("tr.cars").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please note I changed your `id` attribute on your `tr` to have `person-` as prefix, as its not valid HTML to have id's as integers alone.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/06f8czLL/